# Make field names dynamic

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, fields, dynamic

I have two fields on Opportunity called FY1 and FY2. Now, my requirement is that the name of the fields need to be dynamic and change every Financial Year e.g first it would be FY18 and FY19, then next year it would be FY19 and FY20.

What I was thinking is that I will create an object related to the Opportunity and populate them every financial year. Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: you might consider using analytic snapshots for your historical data and then write apps on top of them

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store and report on historical values, a related object is the way to go.

You end up with field-soup if you create new fields on the main object each year. It's a common mistake people make.